# I'm trying to make a program that produces a receipt

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, receipt

I would like for my code to write to a receipt file, the product and price of each barcode entered and then print that file, however, at the moment it stops writing to the file once the first barcode has been entered but continues to ask the questions (it also stops asking for the quantity of products).

The CSV:

```
34512340,bread,2.50,0
98981236,flour,1.79,0
56756777,pasta,1.49,0
90673412,milk,0.89,0
```

The output:

```
Output of code:

Enter a Barcode? (Yes/No):  yes 
Enter Barcode:  56756777 
Enter quantity of products:  7 
Enter a Barcode? (Yes/No):  yes 
Enter Barcode:  98981236 
Enter a Barcode? (Yes/No):  no 
Here is your Receipt: 
56756777    10.43 

Total: 10.43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file pointer moves to the end after one read from the file. The minimum change you can do to make it work is add:

```
f.seek(0)
```

before

```
for column in f:
```

**seek** moves the file pointer to the desired position. Here we are moving it into the start of the file after every time we start checking for the products.

**A better way can be to read the file locally and use it to search for your products**.